# How can Hacking be improved?

Tags: xcom-2

How can the hacking skill of my soldiers be improved?

Which of the following affects it?

- Class (do Specialists get an innate hacking skill boost, or is it only via GREMLIN ?)
- Rank
- Special abilities
- GREMLIN upgrades
- Practise (eg, does attempting/succeeding in a hack improve skill?)

Comment: I'm not sure this is a duplicate.  The other question seems to be more narrowly focused, to the point that it's answer isn't useful for this question.  The answer to this question will probably include some of the same information as that answer, but this question's answer will also include more.  The other answer doesn't mention Class or Rank at all, although it touches on the others (GREMLIN upgrades for the Specialists only, Practise - only certain hacks, not number of times hacked, Special ability - Skulljack).

Comment: If anything, it's probably better to mark the OTHER question as a duplicate, since a complete answer to this question will necessarily include the other question's information.  I know it's uncommon to mark the older, answered question instead of the newer, unanswered one, but in this case I think it would be most helpful, both to the OP(s) and to future readers with the same problem.